# git merge duplicating commits

Tags: git, merge, branch

My scenario is as follows:

I was working on branch A. Someone working on branch B has made changes that I need to continue development on branch A. I ended up checking out to branch B, pulling their changes, checking back to branch A and doing a git merge. Now, on github my files changed includes their files, and my commit history includes their commit history from branch B. It makes sense why this would happen but how do I revert this/go about this problem next time?

Comment: I think what you are asking for is `git rebase`? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior of `git merge`.

Suppose the case:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F branch-A
     \         /
      X---Y---Z branch-B
```

after a merge you'll see a log like:

```
A---B---X---C---Y---D---Z---E---F---(merge commit) branch-A
```

In case you don't want to see the merge commit and still see you teammate commits, you can use `git rebase`.

If you don't want to see the commits of your teammate at all, you can use `git merge --squash` that actually merge the two branches without creating the merge commit and thus without merging the two log histories.